# Monotouch custom back button

Tags: xamarin.ios

I am trying to create a global unique back button
how can i do it so in all my controllers the default back button will be my custom button?

my custom the button is a circle and has '<' inside it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIAppearance` for this, but only in iOS 5 and higher:

```
UIBarButtonItem.Appearance.SetBackButtonBackgroundImage(yourImage, UIControlState.Normal, UIBarMetrics.Default);
```

This is off the top of my head (don't have a Mac in front of me), but the code should be pretty close.

Note, that is applied for every back button in the entire app.